How to include additional fields when registering a user with ASP.NET Core Web API Identity?
I have a custom User class in my ASP.NET Core Web API project, which extends IdentityUser<Guid> from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.
Here's a simplified version of my User class:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System;

namespace Quilt.Models.User
{
    public class UserEntity : IdentityUser<Guid>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        private DateTime _birthday;

        public DateTime Birthday
        {
            get { return _birthday; }
            set
            {
                _birthday = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
        }

        public string? Avatar { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }
}

I'm using ASP.NET Core 8 Identity for user authentication, and currently, during user registration, only the email and password fields are required. However, I want users to provide additional information such as FirstName, LastName, Birthday, Avatar (which is nullable), and Gender during registration.
Here's my Program.cs configuration:
using System.Security.Claims;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Quilt.DataAccess.Data;
using Quilt.Models.User;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddDbContext<QuiltDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddAuthentication().AddBearerToken(IdentityConstants.BearerScheme);

builder.Services.AddAuthorizationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<QuiltDbContext>(options => options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AppDb"));

builder.Services.AddIdentityCore<UserEntity>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<QuiltDbContext>()
    .AddApiEndpoints();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapGroup("/my-identity-api").MapIdentityApi<IdentityUser>();

app.MapGet("/", (ClaimsPrincipal user) => $"Hello {user.Identity!.Name}").RequireAuthorization();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.Run();

How can I modify my registration process to include these additional fields from the UserEntity class? Should I customize the registration endpoint, and if so, how can I achieve this while still leveraging ASP.NET Core Identity for authentication?
Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

You could try following:
Create RegisterDTO.cs
    public class RegisterDTO
    {
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }    
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
        public string? Avatar { get; set; }
        public string Gender { get; set; }
    }

Create a IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs and copy all the codes from this link https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Identity/Core/src/IdentityApiEndpointRouteBuilderExtensions.cs
Replace all the MapIdentityApi to MapCustomIdentityApi in this file. And add modify the inherit to where TUser: UserEntity, new()

Change the "/register" endpoint registeration model to RegisterDTO

Under this endpoint change
 to
        var user = new TUser
        {
            Email = registration.Email,
            FirstName = registration.FirstName,
            LastName = registration.LastName,
            Birthday = registration. Birthday,
            Avatar = registration.Avatar,
            Gender = registration.Gender
        };

In the program.cs use app.MapCustomIdentityApi<UserEntity>(); instead.
Test result


Worked for me , thanks

I recently added Firstname and Lastname fields in Asp.Net Core 8.0 Identity. I think the main part you're missing is to Scaffold some of the /Identity/Pages/Account pages so that you can override/customize them. These 2 sites explain how to add custom fields to Identity:

Best Instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/add-user-data?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio
Also Helpful: How to add first/last name properties to Identity user in ASP.NET Core MVC?

The above describe the numerous steps needed to do it right--more involved and time-consuming than one might expect. I found it very worthwhile to first create a brand new VisualStudio Asp.Net Core web project so I could follow the instructions and grasp concepts in a "clean" project, without risk of breaking my actual one. After learning how to do it, repeating the steps in my actual project was much easier.
The following are the high-level steps:

Create a custom class that inherits : IdentityUser and extends it by adding your custom fields. (It appears you
have done this with your UserEntity class.)
Create a new custom data context that inherits IdentityDbContext for your custom IdentityUser type, e.g. Public Class BoostersIdentityDbContext : IdentityDbContext<BoostersIdentityUser> { }.
Scaffold several of the Identity pages so you can modify them. At minimum you'll need to scaffold then customize /Account/Manage/Index and /Account/Register. There are 3 places in each .cs code backing file to add your fields, and then adding your fields to the .cshtml pages. This is probably the step you have been missing.
Migrate or manually add the fields to your database.

One thing to watch out for:
Upon scaffolding any Identity pages, the scaffolder seems to ALWAYS add the following AddDefaultIdentity line to my Program.cs file which I must delete every time:
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<BoostersIdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true).AddEntityFrameworkStores<BoostersIdentityDbContext>();

because I already have a non-default Identity service that includes Roles, e.g.:
builder.Services.AddIdentity<BoostersIdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options => 
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
    })
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
    .AddDefaultUI()
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<BoostersIdentityDbContext>();


Hmmm, I just noticed you said Web API -- My answer above was for Website, so perhaps the Scaffolding of Pages was not pertinent to your API project. I hope it can help others, though.
